# Does the .Net Threadpool provide any mechanisms to avoid I/O performance degradation when a lot of CPU intensive work is scheduled?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, threadpool

I have a pretty specific question about the .NET threadpool.

I would say I have a pretty fair understanding of the threadpool, but one thing still boggles my mind.

Let's assume I run a web application which serves requests, but also performs a lot of heavy duty CPU-bound work by rendering / editing uploaded media.

Common advice when it comes to separating I/O and CPU bound tasks in an application would be to dispatch the CPU bound work to the .Net ThreadPool. Concrete, that would mean dispatching the call with `Task.Run(...)` - So far so good.

However, I do wonder, what would happen if this is done for **a lot** of requests. Let's say several hundreds / thousands, enough to really put an enourmous strain on a machine, and even up to the point the Threadpool just can't handle it anymore. Adding more Threads would obviously go only so far, when your CPU can't handle more. I would say at this point the Threadpool's Threads are also at the mercy of the CPU itself, and the scheduling algorithm.

What implications would this have on I/O bound async operations?

Would this cause I/O bound async operations to struggle with executing their continuation? Given we are in a runtime environment which executes async/await continuations on the Threadpool and discards the SynchronizationContext, what would ensure that these would still execute properly?

Does the Threadpool make any sophisticated assumption as to which Thread receives scheduling priority, to ensure throughput even when it's absolutely polluted with work?

It would be especially interesting to know how ASP.Net Core deals with this, since the request handlers are supposedly Threadpool Threads themselves.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23189090/11683? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64739992/11683? https://medium.com/criteo-engineering/net-threadpool-starvation-and-how-queuing-makes-it-worse-512c8d570527?

Comment: Scheduling is performed by the operating system, not the ThreadPool. It's the OS itself that assigns priorities. On Windows IO is *alway* asynchronous at the driver level. Synchronous execution is emulated by blocking until the IO completes.

Comment: I am no expert myself, but I don't think you have an understanding of the thread pool. The idea of a thread pool is to _not_ create threads for every task, but to reuse threads in the thread pool. A thread pool will typically have a number of threads equal to the number of virtual cores available, including hyper threading virtual cores. This way old fashioned very expensive thread scheduling in the OS is replaced with dirt cheap scheduling of tasks within the application. Having a great number of tasks is not a problem in itself. It scales "more linearly".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Let's assume I run a web application which serves requests, but also performs a lot of heavy duty CPU-bound work by rendering / editing uploaded media.
>
> Common advice when it comes to separating I/O and CPU bound tasks in an application would be to dispatch the CPU bound work to the .Net ThreadPool. Concrete, that would mean dispatching the call with Task.Run(...) - So far so good.

No, that's bad advice.

ASP.NET is already handling the request on a thread pool thread, so switching to *another* thread pool thread via `Task.Run` isn't going to help anything - in fact, it'll make things worse.

`Task.Run` is fine to offload CPU work to the thread pool when the calling method is a *GUI* thread. However, it's not a good idea to use `Task.Run` on ASP.NET, generally speaking.

> However, I do wonder, what would happen if this is done for a lot of requests. Let's say several hundreds / thousands, enough to really put an enourmous strain on a machine, and even up to the point the Threadpool just can't handle it anymore. Adding more Threads would obviously go only so far, when your CPU can't handle more.

The thread pool will inject threads whenever the thread pool is over-full. However, the injection rate is limited, so the thread pool grows slowly.

> What implications would this have on I/O bound async operations? Would this cause I/O bound async operations to struggle with executing their continuation? ... what would ensure that these would still execute properly?

First off, the I/O requests themselves (and their lowest-level, BCL-internal continuations) are not affected. That's because "the" thread pool is actually two thread pools: there's worker threads (that execute queued work) and there's I/O threads (that enlist in the I/O completion port and handle low-level I/O completion).

However, at some point most continuations do transition to the worker thread pool, so by the time *your* code continues, it needs a regular thread pool thread to do so. And yes, that means that if the (worker) thread pool is saturated, then that can starve `await` continuations.

Having ASP.NET handlers do heavy CPU work is unusual. The thread pool does have a lot of knobs to tweak if you do need to support it. And there's always the option of splitting the CPU-bound APIs internally into a separate API, which would give you two different ASP.NET apps: one I/O-bound and the other CPU-bound, which would let you tune the thread pool appropriately for each.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! What if my Asp.Net Thread would want to do multiple CPU-bound things in parallel, and would Task.Run(..) e.g. 10 different sets of work at once, would this be the correct approach in that case?

Comment: @nugetminer23: I don't recommend it. It's super easy to cause a denial-of-service on yourself by doing parallel work on ASP.NET.

Comment: I understand. If I need to schedule a synchronous operation to a later point in time though (The request should already finish, while the work is done), would this be a use case where Task.Run is reasonable? Or would I wrap the call in a function with a Task.Yield, while not awaiting the function, in order to ensure the work continues on the calling context?

Comment: @nugetminer23: Neither. You should use [a basic distributed architecture](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html), as I describe on my blog.

Comment: *"The thread pool will inject threads whenever the thread pool is over-full."* -- What happens when the [`ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.getavailablethreads) have been reduced to zero, and no more new threads can be injected? I think that the OP describes this scenario, when the hard limit has been reached.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: I suppose if the thread pool hit the hard limit ([64k worker threads on 64-bit machines](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/264d7391ec9f6e698051db0621c5e090d0ae4710/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/PortableThreadPool.cs#LL22C69-L22C69)), then the thread pool would block and likely cause a deadlock. I've never been in that situation, since other resources have always run out before I hit 64k threads.

Comment: Do you have any idea, or even a guess, about how the ASP.NET Core will react if the hard limit has been reached, and all the pending requests are blocked at a line like `var result = Task.Run(() => /*...*/).Result`? Is there any timeout mechanism that will start aborting threads after a while, or the whole site will come to a halt forever?

Comment: I couldn't say for sure; I expect it would deadlock. There's a pretty good chance it would never recover, since most asynchronous APIs require a thread pool thread to complete. Core does not terminate threads at all AFAIK - certainly not for timeouts.